# Scala Breeze prefix scalar multiplication

Tags: scala, scala-breeze

When using Breeze do I have to import some implicit conversions to make prefix scalar multiplication work?

```
val v = DenseVector(1.0, 2.0, 3.0)
val r = 2.0 * v
```

The above doesn't work, where as:

```
val r = v * 2.0
```

Does work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Breeze doesn't define any implicit conversions for Double etc. right now. I should add them, but there's nothing yet.